# Howto use CoffeeScript with yeoman webapp generator and require.js?

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs, yeoman

After updating from yeoman pre1.0 to most recent 1.0.0beta3 I'm getting more and more frustrated by yeoman.

What worked like a charme out of the box in pre1.0 does not work anymore and documentation is hard to find. Thought yo should make things easier, not harder - sry.

My goal, simple: I'd like to create a backbone based app using require.js and coffee files. So I created a directory structure below the `scripts` directory that was generated by `yo webapp`.

Every coffee file in those subdirectories is ignored by the coffee task. Even after adding the subdirectory search in Gruntfile.js it does not work.

Is there any piece of documentation that I can dig into spending hours? Get the feeling, I'd be faster using middleman with a custom built build process. And sadly that's the opposite of yeoman's initial goals I think.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that yeoman made you frustrated, we are working hard to give you the best experience.

We have updated the Yeoman [backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) to support [RequireJS](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/22). But still **CoffeeScript is not supported with RequireJS**.

We are working on resolving this and will update once its done.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to get requirejs to work with coffeescript.  It works great when running grunt server, but when running grunt requirejs complained about not being able to find the proper js files.  I was able to make some changes to my Gruntfile to get it to work.  I posted the code here

https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/956#issuecomment-16556615

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx Nick. Finally I fiddled with the Gruntfile as well as long as it worked for build. Thx anway.